# Google Static Map Displays on Computer but Not on Mobile

Tags: google-maps

So this code was working just fine about a week ago and I went to check it today before the review and sure as hell its not working. I checked on the online website to make sure the map was displaying and it was displaying correctly online on my PC. However when I view the same address on my phone I get an error image that looks like this.

[image: Google Map Image Error]

Pretty sure my code is fine. Not Sure what this is related to. I had the API key in there before and I thought that I was exceeding the amount of requests until I looked up the amount of requests that Google allows which is 25,000 a day. This page is not even used yet so that is not possible.

It does not work on Android phones or iPhones. Anybody seen this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after researching some more it is because I exceeded the amount of requests. Not sure how this is possible so I will have to check the API console to look at my analytic's.

Here is the link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Limits

Answer (score 1):

The "over limit" image which you are seeing is because Google has determined that too many requests are reaching their servers from a single location.

Mobile phone companies proxy their internet requests, so Google thinks that all the requests come from a single IP address. The requests *should* be well-behaved and use an `X-FORWARDED-FOR` header to indicate the use of a proxy and the real origin, but some aren't. Or Google may misinterpret the results from those headers.

The solution is to change your mobile provider.

Because requests for identical maps are cached and don't count towards statistics, it's not even viable to make each of your requests unique (by slightly varying the centre of the map, for example). There really isn't anything you can do in the request for the map.